# iframes: how do I layer a specific iframe with navigation menu in it on top of all other iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to layer iframes so the frame with the navigation menu is on top of all other iframes. the nav menu is a css dropdown tab menu navigation. The problem is when a drop menu appears from a category being hovered over it displays behind the main iframe (iframe_b) that displays the content.

```css
<html>
<body bgcolor="black" text="red">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar" position:top;>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<iframe height="30px" width="100%" src="menu.html" name="iframe_a" style="border:none;scrolling:no;"></iframe>
<iframe height="85%" width="100%" src="CONTENT_PANE" name="iframe_b" style="border:none;"></iframe>
<iframe height="40
```

I need iframe_a, the menu to be on top of all of the other frames so when there is a drop down it appears on top of iframe_b's content. How do I accomplish this?

I did what I'm trying to do 15+ years ago on another site I built was with z-index but I don't have that site's code to reference anymore and I of course can't remember exactly how I did it. From what I vaguely remember it was extremely simple to do, it was just one line (z-index:something) in the body tag placed in the  section.

I'm new to the site and not familiar with how to format everything. The HTML in the HTML pane of the snippet (fiddle??) is the "indext.html". The content in the CSS pane is an example of the navigation menu for iframe_a.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply styling to particular `iframe`, because stylesheet from `index.html` can't format iframe **contents**, like dropdown menu from one of `iframe`s. Set `z-index` value for the "top" `iframe` (Dropdown-menu I suppose) to some big number, like 999 and some smaller number for the other `iframe`s

Example:

````html
<iframe height="30px" width="100%" src="menu.html" name="iframe_a" style="border:none;scrolling:no; z-index:999;"></iframe>
<iframe height="85%" width="100%" src="CONTENT_PANE" name="iframe_b" style="border:none; z-index:10;"></iframe>```
````

Comment: Thanks, Kaper365. I tried what you suggested before and it didn't work for what I was trying to do. I was using the wrong tags is what it was. I was using <div>s to make the menu instead of list tags (<ul><li>) and I was using iframes for both the menu and the content pane. It worked when I changed to using list for the menu and only one iframe for the content. Your answer was the boost I needed! Thank you!